# Problems with Java HashMaps and putAll() method

Tags: java, hashmap

Hey everybody, 
I am writing a program that compares the running times of various Dijkstra implementations. I parse the relevant info from a text file and enter it into a hashtable. In my current implementation I have a 'master' hashtable that holds the Node info and that info is copied into a temporary hashtable which is then passed onto different Dijkstra classes.

```
public class Router
{
    public static Map <Integer, Node> nodes = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();
    public static Map <Integer, Node> temp = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();
    public static int target = 2;
    public static int start = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Parser p3 = new Parser(args[0], nodes, p);
        temp.putAll(nodes);

        // Test 1
        DijkstraFib fb = new DijkstraFib(temp, start, target, p);
        temp.clear();
        temp.putAll(nodes);

        //Test 2
        DijkstraBinary d = new DijkstraBinary(temp, start, target, p);
        temp.clear();
        temp.putAll(nodes);

        // Test 3
        Dijkstra b = new Dijkstra(temp, start, target, p);
    }
```

}

So rather then having to invoke a parser three times for each Dijkstra class, I simply want to copy all the values from `nodes` table to `temp`, since `temp` gets modified during the method execution. The first two tests run fine, but the third test fails. If I swap Test 2 and Test 3 around then Test 2 fails; basically, whichever test is run last, fails. Here's my Dijkstra method:

```
void route(Map <Integer, Node> nodes, int source)
{
    Node start = nodes.get(source);
    start.distance = 0;
    unsettledNodes.add(start);

    while(!unsettledNodes.isEmpty())
    {
        Node n = extractMin();
        visited.put(n.name, n);
        relax_neighbours(n, nodes);
    }
}

void relax_neighbours(Node n, Map <Integer, Node> nodes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n.outgoing.size(); i++)
    {
        Edge edge = n.outgoing.get(i);
        Node v = nodes.get(edge.node);

        if (isSettled(v))
        {
            continue;
        }

        double shortDist = n.distance + edge.length;
        if (shortDist < v.distance)
        {
            unsettledNodes.remove(v);
            v.distance = shortDist;
            v.previous = n;
            unsettledNodes.add(v);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my method that prints the path starting from the target node:

```
 void print_path(Map <Integer, Node> visited, int i)
{
    ArrayList<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();

    for (Node target = visited.get(i); target != null; target = target.previous)
    {
        path.add(target);
    }
    System.out.println("Simple Dijkstra took " + this.time_taken + " ms");
    System.out.print("Min dist from " + this.source + " to " + this.target + " = " + path.get(0).distance + " : ");

    Collections.reverse(path);

    System.out.print(path.get(0).name);
    p.append(Integer.toString(path.get(0).name));
    for (int k = 1; k < path.size(); k++)
    {
        System.out.print(" -> " + path.get(k).name);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and here's the console output:

```
Edges: 948464
Fibonacci Dijkstra took 340 ms
Min dist from 0 to 2 = 89.0 : 0 -> 195 -> 5523 -> 5504 -> 5870 -> 5835 -> 3076 -> 15319 -> 5588 -> 5911 -> 2

Binary Dijkstra took 302292 ms
Min dist from 0 to 2 = 89.0 : 0 -> 195 -> 5523 -> 5504 -> 5870 -> 5835 -> 3076 -> 15319 -> 5588 -> 5911 -> 2

Simple Dijkstra took 0 ms
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
   at Dijkstra.print_path(Dijkstra.java:115)
   at Dijkstra.<init>(Dijkstra.java:25)
   at Router.main(Router.java:33)
```

Comment: was there an exception raised? if yes can you post that too pls?

Comment: oops, forgot to get rid of that before I pasted it here. The 'p' is a PrintStream variable (code not above). I am logging the algorithm running times into a txt file for future use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, I can't tell for sure, but it looks like you're passing the same objects around when you putAll in the new maps.  That is, the same nodes are being referenced from call to call and temp is *not* copy of the values in nodes.  If your methods are modifying the path weights for the shortest path algorithms (i.e., if Node is mutable), you're going to run into issues.

One option is to write a deep copy method for your node by creating a new node and populating all the relevant info.  Then you will have a 'fresh' copy of the node for each new run of the algorithm

Comment: Instead of a deep copy, a method that returns a fresh map with the same data every time might be easier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I go about writing a method that returns a fresh map with the same data? From the answer above I gather that rather then passing the copies of my nodes, temp contains the actual nodes.

Comment: @Jeremy - so, like a deep copy of the hashmap? :)

Comment: @user283188 - the problem stems from the fact that the objects are the same when using putAll.  You'll need to write a method to 1) create a new hashmap 2) populate that hashmap with the same data as @Jeremy mentions.  Passing the keys as-is should be fine, but the Node objects need to be copied by, for example, creating a new node and setting every variable in the node the value of the existing one.

Comment: @spinning_plate sounds like an overkill for what I perceived to be a simple problem/stupid mistake on my part. I understand where the problem is so thank you very much for that. Let me ask you this though - if you look at the output paths of the first two algorithm runs, the path distances remain unchanged, even though everyone pointed out that each algorithm run directly modifies the main node distances. Why do you think that is?

Comment: @user283188 - good question. Without playing with the code, I'm not sure.  What does it look like if you output all the values of the nodes? Specifically, does node.distance = node.weight on all inputs?

Answer (score 2):

The Exception (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException) mean you trying to get element which is out of range in your array.

The problem is in 115 line in method print_path:

```
at Dijkstra.print_path(Dijkstra.java:115)
```

Try use your debugger to know what state of your variables you have when exception is encountered. To do this set breakpoint in method print_path at 115 line, and check why you're getting element from non existing index.

**edited:**
The problem is because when you call putAll() you put references to your main nodes, after it your algorithm modify nodes (**actually in your nodes HashMap**) and this will be propagate in the next tests.

Comment: The line 115 is: System.out.print("Min dist from " + this.source + " to " + this.target + " = " + path.get(0).distance + " : "); the method print_path() is the same for all three Dijkstra classes, but it always fails whenever one of the classes is run third.

Comment: So path.get(0).distance cause the problem because in this situation path array has 0 elements. I think the Path array is empty because in 3rd call you have in your for-loop visited.get(i) == null

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out why that happens. Each Dijkstra class has its own 'public Map <Integer, Node> visited = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();' and my 'route()' method adds nodes to it, so I am puzzled as to why it would misbehave on the third call.

Comment: and that's why bad idea is to use static variables :)

Comment: do you mean static in front of nodes and temp hashtables?

Comment: Thanks for your help; I understand where the problem is now. However, if you look at the output paths of the first two algorithm runs, the path distances remain unchanged, even though everyone pointed out that each algorithm run directly modifies the main node distances. I am curious about your opinion on this one. :)

Comment: exatly! remember that in java when you put object to the Map (Collection) you are putting **reference**, so beware a modification :)